# What is the word/expression that is pronounced something like "bee-ah"?

Tags: prononciation, expressions-idiomatiques

My French teacher says a couple of expressions pretty often. Some of them I understand, but there's an expression I cannot figure out what it means. The problem is I can't google it because I don't know how to write it, all I know is that it sounds something like *bee-ah*, and that it is used like a filler, along with *c'est a dire*. That may be all, or just a part of it. I know it's not much, but that's all I can say.

Comment: Could be *ben*, *bah* maybe.

Comment: Maybe she says **bien**. It means **good**.

Comment: Thanks for the try, but I know it's not that because nasal vowels are pretty distinguishable. I can tell the word doesn't end with an 'n'.

Comment: You should not be too assertive. There is absolutely no doubt what you describe is ***bien***, which means "**well**" here, not "good" by the way.

Comment: Maybe I should have also said the stress is in the first syllable ('bee-ah rather than bee-'ah). Does that make sense?

Comment: Is your teacher a terrorist? If not, then you are lucky because you can ask her directly.

Comment: *Bien* might be stressed that way.

Comment: I agree with @Begueradj, it is very hard to guess with so few elements, you'd better ask your teacher... :)

Comment: I'm not going to class anymore, this was something I just never asked and was curious about, but thanks you all for the feedback!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Could it be “[*b.a.-ba*](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/b.a.-ba)” \be.a.ba\?

“*Le b.a.-ba*” is the very basic knowledge of a topic. It comes from the use of [phonics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phonics) as a means of teaching reading: a *b* followed by a *a* is pronounced *ba* – it’s the very first phoneme you can write using the alphabetical order.

Comment: I'm puzzled by how this can match what the OP has heard and reported as "Bee-ah". Either the teacher was talking in French and that would have been transcripted "Bay-ah bah" or in English and that would have been something like "Bee-Ay Bay".