# Usage of the number "101" in French to mean introductory level of learning or the most basic knowledge of something

Tags: traduction, anglais, usage, nombres

> The term (101) was first introduced by the University of Buffalo in 1929.
> It was used as a course catalog, the first known usage of the term by
> Oxford English Dictionary. Based on this usage, the term "101" has been extended to mean an
> introductory level of learning or a collection of introductory
> materials to a topic. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/101_(topic)

See also the thread: https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/14265/what-does-something-101-mean.

I encountered this French article: [Électronique d'Imagerie 101 : Compréhension des Capteurs de Caméra pour les Applications de Vision Industrielle](https://www.edmundoptics.fr/knowledge-center/application-notes/imaging/understanding-camera-sensors-for-machine-vision-applications/). Is this usage of 101 colloquial in French?

Furthermore 101 has also the meaning of "*showing the most basic knowledge about a subject*". [See: https://dictionary.cambridge.org/fr/dictionnaire/anglais/101]

E.g.

> You should know how to boil an egg - that's cooking 101.

Can we use 101 in this way (i.e. as an adjective) in French? If not, what are some colloquial ways to convey a similar idea?

Comment: For your information, a basic course in something is a 101 course in something. That is not a colloquial expression. Also, the second use is not really colloquial; it's just idiomatic and means the basics of something.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The term ***101*** is not used at all in France with this or any specific meaning.

The cited title is just a (too) direct translation of an English one:
[Imaging Electronics 101: Understanding Camera Sensors for Machine Vision Applications](https://www.edmundoptics.com/knowledge-center/application-notes/imaging/understanding-camera-sensors-for-machine-vision-applications/).

The closest expression would be [*B.A.-BA*, or *béaba*](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/b.a.-ba) already mentioned here:

https://french.stackexchange.com/a/17003/1109

[b a ba, /beaba/ or /bøaba/?](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/37436/b-a-ba-beaba-or-b%c3%b8aba)

e.g.:

> Tu devrais savoir faire cuire un œuf dur, c'est le b.a.-ba de la cuisine !

On the other hand, the number 101 is used in Quebec, for example in this video series: *[Québécois 101](https://www.wanderingfrench.com/qc-001/)*

Comment: So, I guess, the French article cited in my question, could be just an one to one translation of an English article. Thanks for the answer.

Comment: It is indeed: [Imaging Electronics 101: Understanding Camera Sensors for Machine Vision Applications](https://www.edmundoptics.com/knowledge-center/application-notes/imaging/understanding-camera-sensors-for-machine-vision-applications/)

Comment: I'm an anglophone from Montréal, so French is not my first language.  However I did spend the first 34 years of my life in Montréal (including 6 in Trois Rivières).  I don't remember ever hearing _B.A.-BA_ before.  So I asked my wife (who learned French in the late elementary school/early high school while at a Lycée in Algeria).  She'd heard it before, but she doesn't remember ever hearing it in Montréal (where she finished up high school and lived until she was 34).  Is that a French from France only expression?

Comment: @Flydog57 It is definitely used in Québec, maybe less that in European French but here are examples from native Quebecers: 1. [Le b.a.-ba de l’édition génomique](https://www.lapresse.ca/debats/opinions/2021-12-16/alimentation/le-b-a-ba-de-l-edition-genomique.php), 2. [LE B.A.-BA D’UNE EXPÉRIENCE RÉUSSIE](https://veilletourisme.ca/2018/11/19/b-a-ba-experience-reussie/), 3. [Le b-a ba de la culture en contenant](https://m.espacepourlavie.ca/blogue/le-b-a-ba-de-la-culture-en-contenant)

Comment: J'aime bien B.A.-BA parce qu'il est basé sur la reconnaissance d'une séquence de lettres du début de l'alphabet. Similairement, _101_ est une première séquence d'une série. Cette adéquation morphologique ou fonctionnelle me plaît et ajoute à la qualité de cette traduction à mon avis.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/134327/discussion-on-answer-by-jlliagre-usage-of-the-number-101-in-french-to-mean-int).

Answer (score 2):

In France, a 101 course can be expressed as: **introduction à**:
as in:

**Introduction à** la chimie organique
Parcours : Sciences de la vie franco-allemand

[Université de Strasbourg](https://sciencesvie.unistra.fr/formation/licence/sciences-de-la-vie-franco-allemand?tx_unistrarof_pi1%5Brof-course%5D=FRUAI0673021VCOEN1153&tx_unistrarof_pi1%5Brof-program%5D=ME3&cHash=2cd45e5a7dd1b3c5f6a4f7c339bdde19)

**Introduction à** l'histoire contemporaine

[Université de Strasbourg](https://histoire.unistra.fr/formation/licence/histoire-de-lart-et-archeologie/histoire-de-lart/rof/ME13/FRUAI0673021VCOEN492?cHash=b4068e3f1f7293c0ef40a465f88f6d57)

**Cours d’introduction historique au droit et histoire des institutions**, par Eric Gojosso

[Université de Poitiers](https://droit.univ-poitiers.fr/cours-dintroduction-historique-au-droit-et-dhistoire-des-institutions-par-eric-gojosso/)

**That's for the first meaning of a 101 course** in some subject area.

Now, "That's cooking 101" (*showing basic knowledge of a subject*) could be said **in many ways.** **And in English, it means**: That's **cooking for beginners.**

"**Ça, c'est de la cuisine pour débutants**.

[Please note: I am specifically not referring to Québec as I am simply do not know what this idea would be there. 101 means an introductory course in higher education. A Phd-level course can be: 401, for example. These course numberings are American English originally.]

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/134328/discussion-on-answer-by-lambie-usage-of-the-number-101-in-french-to-mean-intro).

Answer (score 1):

On trouve certainement au Québec des emplois avec « 101 » en adjectif (avec par exemple sur [*LaPresse*](https://www.lapresse.ca/recherche?q=101%20-%22loi%20101%22#gsc.tab=0&gsc.q=101%20-%22loi%20101%22&gsc.page=1) : *canot, potagers, populisme, rénovations, économie, testament* etc.), pour signifier ce qu'on a identifié dans les autres réponses ([*ba.ba*](https://french.stackexchange.com/a/41849), [*introduction à*](https://french.stackexchange.com/a/49776)). J'ajouterais l'*abc/notions élémentaires/bases de*, possiblement utiles ; [*Termium*](https://www.btb.termiumplus.gc.ca/tpv2alpha/alpha-eng.html?lang=eng&srchtxt=101&i=&index=enw&sg_kp_wet=1997233&fchrcrdnm=15#fichesauve-saverecord15) recense une traduction de titre de monographie *L'abc des mots de passe* pour *Passwords 101*. Savoir faire cuire un oeuf à la coque, c'est à mon avis un truc *de base, la base, élémentaire* voire *fondamental*.

Comment: ba.ba ne marche pas pour 101. Et oui, au Québec, je vois qu'on utilise 101 + un sujet comme potagers ou économie.  ba.ba en anglais veut dire the basics of [subject matter].

Comment: @Lambie Ba.ba marche pour 101 jusqu'à preuve du contraire et une telle preuve n'a pas été faite. [101](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/101) peut signifier _basic_. Ton choix de traduire ba.ba en _basics_ ne détermine rien du tout dans l'univers et n'empêcherait pas de traduire 101 par ba.ba ou l'inverse.