# Conveying 'the nuts and bolts of something'

Tags: traduction, expressions, anglais

When one says ''the nuts and bolts of something' they mean 'the basic facts or practical things that need to be understood or done'. For example

> He was a genius on paper, but when it came to the nuts and bolts of running a business he was a failure.

I am thinking about

> C'était un génie en théorie, mais quand il s'agissait des rudiments d'une entreprise, il était un échec.

but I guess there are better ways to express the idea.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Sur le papier, c'était un génie, mais quand il lui a fallu se conformer au [**B.A.-BA**](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/41842/usage-of-the-number-101-in-french-to-mean-introductory-level-of-learning-or-th) de la gestion d'entreprise, il s'est planté.

On pourrait aussi dire :

> ...lui a fallu se confronter aux **fondamentaux** de la gestion...
> ...lui a fallu affronter les **détails pratiques** de la gestion...
> ...lui a fallu maîtriser un tant soit peu les **rouages** de la gestion...

Answer (score 3):

Une variante possible :

> mais quand il s'est confronté à la réalité du terrain...